# Missing package in Ubuntu SDK - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-webapps-api

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, qt5, sdk

Installing the Ubuntu SDK failed because of missing package

```
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-webapps-api
```

this was the message from apt-get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-html5-sdk : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-webapps-api but it is not installable
                    Depends: ubuntu-html5-container but it is not going to be installed
```

Can I get this package somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ubuntu-html5-sdk` metapackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-html5-sdk) only exists in *Trusty* (14.04), for which [`qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin) should also be available (even though it shouldn't be required, according to the package details).

- Are you installing the SDK from the package repository? If so, is your package index up to date? Run `apt-get update` to make sure.
- If you're installing from a PPA, notify its maintainer of your problem.
- If everything else fails, you *could* install the dependencies manually and then retry the installation, but I would advise against it, as it will prevent you from receiving automatic updates and is **very** likely to break things (due to incompatible versions).

Comment: Mike thanks for answering. I followed the same steps I took yesterday and on the http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/ page I found this notice: NOTICE: The PPA below currently has a broken package dependency and will not work correctly. We are working on resolving this issue as quickly as possible.
I tried installing again and so far everything is working. If there is another fail I'll post a follow up. Thanks again. - Ray